# Include multiple library dependency in same project JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, cmake, java-native-interface

I'm trying to build an android app using JNI. The following is my C++ code structure:

```
main
  -cpp
    -native-lib.cpp
    -dependency.h
    -dependency.cpp
```

In my `native-lib.cpp` I'm including `dependency.h`. In my Cmake, I'm creating a shared library (.so) for `dependency` and `native-lib` so that I can load them in my Java part of the code.

While building the code however I cannot build `native-lib` because it has a dependency on `dependency`. For a quick fix, I'm building the `dependency` first and then linking it to `native-lib` and then loading the two in my java side. But I know it is the wrong way of doing things, hence I wanted to know the right way of adding multiple dependencies in JNI.

The following is my Cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
include_directories(Include)
add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        dependency

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        dependency.cpp )

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        native-lib

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        native-lib.cpp )

# Once the so is being built I'm adding it myself and linking it. 
# I don't want to do this but link it automatically
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        native-lib

        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libdependency.so)
```

Here is the Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("dependency");
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }
    
    // Some other functions
}
```

PS: Not adding `target_link_libraries` to link `libdependency.so` thinking that Java `LoadLibrary` will link it in real-time does not build as native-lib would have undefined references

Comment: Why not simply `target_link_libraries(native-lib dependency)`? Then CMake will generate proper build dependencies in the `Makefile`.

Comment: I did try it but it's not working. I tried the same before even putting this question it's in the ps part. It works every time I do it but this time idk what's happening and hence the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android, you only need to explicitly `loadLibrary("dependency")` if the platform is older than API 21. As for **CMake**,

```
target_link_libraries(native-lib dependency)
```

should work, but you may need to clean the project if the CMake caches don't get properly updated.

Comment: thanks, it started working once I cleaned and rebuilt the project. Felt so stupid